# maintaining session key with backup services

Tags: microservices, restful-authentication

How is the session key/token is maintained for Resful web service, when the main microservice is crashed and the backup service has to run? in otherwords, how the backup service (all) will get the session details?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for microservices is, to be stateless.

That means, the service should not cache the session key or token. Session details should be maintained in a caching service like Redis.

And each instance of the microservice is equal. There should be no distinction like "main" and "backup" instance. All instances will have access to the redis cache.

A service request should include the token. BTW, the browser can do this for you.

The servicing instance, which could be any, first query the cache for the session details and then proceed accordingly - redirect to login if none found; validate session validity, access rights etc, if a valid token is found.

Comment: If you could please check : https://stackoverflow.com/q/52436548/7510748