# IP Control for backup services and connection with Registery Service

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka

let's take Eureka.
in a normal scenario, A microservice is registered with the Eureka, and we get its information there.
the microservice has multiple backup servers.
the question is, how these servers will be registered in Eureka.
Will all the Backup servers have different IP or same IP!
how the registration for backup servers happen, and how the backup server is chosen.